# Database queries vs quick response

Tags: database, django, optimization, architecture

We are making a gamification component for our forum, which is being developed in Django. We would like users to receive badges right away after achieving certain goals. However, we are concerned about the amount of database queries that would be made. For example, take a badge that is given if a post gets a certain amount of views. If the condition for the badge is checked every time the post is viewed, that would be a lot of queries. Is our only other option to check at certain intervals or another event, like the user viewing their profile? That would be less optimal from the user perspective, because of the delay.

Comment: SO has a delay, and it's quite ok from the user perspective.

Comment: Indeed, I'm wondering if there's a way to know more about SO's badge system?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of using signals to update a counter field and assign the badge when the desired goal is achieved?

Comment: @nabucosound: Yes that's what we've been doing, we're using a database table to record stats including the number of views, so each time a post get viewed, a database query is called to get the value of "views"(In this case, doing a sum of all questions with more than certain number of views). If there're lots of people using the site, there'll be a lot of db calls just for checking badges' conditions, which may use too much resources. And that's what I'm worrying about

Answer (score 0):

There is a different approach that may suit you, using webserver logging and post-processing that log to generate stats. I have used it in Apache with some projects that required pageview hit counts. A similar configuration for other webservers would work the same.

I use *django.contrib.contentypes* to write down the Content Type ID and Object ID of the object accessed on this example, but you can, of course, log anything you want.

So, in your Apache virtualhost conf file, adding a LogFormat directive like this:

```
LogFormat "%{X-H-CID}o|%{X-H-OID}o" hitcounter
```

And then attaching it to a CustomLog:

```
CustomLog path/to/your/logfile.log hitcounter
```

This will enable Apache to write down to the logfile the following HTTP headers: X-H-CID and X-H-OID, which represent the ContentType ID and Object ID of the object being hit. From a view, you may add the headers to the HttpResponse:

```
ctxt = RequestContext(request) 
rendered = render_to_string(template, ctxt)
http_res = HttpResponse(rendered) 
http_res['X-H-CID'] = content_type_id
http_res['X-H-OID'] = object_id
```

Replace content_type_id and object_id with your real object props.

This example should write a line like:

```
16|4353
```

where 16 is the Content Type ID and 4353 the Object ID. Finally, you can schedule a django custom command to process that logfile and perform the needed actions.

Comment: Hi nabucosound! Thanks for the answer, I'm wondering if recording the visiting history in database is the same as writing them in a file? And my main concern is at which moment the calculation should be performed to grant users with badges, so the users get them more or less "on time" while not consuming too much server resource.

Comment: If you use this solution above, you will have to set up a cron job that parses the log and updates the badges accordingly. The more frequently (every minute, for instance) the more sync your user will receive the badges.

Comment: I don't know about your expected traffic, but I'd guess that you can run for the database approach and monitor your performance. Or maybe you could set up a different database only to mantain those badges, and use Django's multi-database feature with routers to link it to your project...

Comment: Thanks nabucosound! The answer is a bit of too specific to the viewing count, which is only a specific type of badge. And the logging method seems like an overkill for my problem.
At the moment I'll try to evaluate the badge conditions each time a signal is fired (an action is carried out by the user). And see in test if the traffic goes too heavy.